# Error JDK and JRE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-6

Good morning, I created a web application project by Google, simple, with nothing in it. I'm trying to deploy my project, and is giving the following error: Can not get the Java Compiler System. Please use the JDK, not the JRE.

I replaced the window -> preferences -> Java -> installed JREs to use the JDK. When I change this, an error in the compilation of index.jsp: Your project must be configured to use the JDK in order to use JSPs.

And now, I put JRE to make deploy and error in jsp, jsp and the concert I can not do deploy. What can I do?

Comment: I think you have not installed the JDK..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set your JDK as your default JAVA_HOME variable and Path variable ?

My Computer -> Properties -> advanced settings -> Environment variables :

- edit JAVA_HOME value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x
- edit Path value by adding : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x\bin

Comment: If you have the JAVA_HOME variable is better to use %JAVA_HOME%\bin in the path instead of rewritting the whole path. If you need to change it later you have only to change the JAVA_HOME var...

Comment: JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%
Path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin 

It'´s right?

Comment: JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME% is like a declaring int a = a; it doesn't mean anything. Use this :  JAVA_HOME value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x (path depends on your jdk version) and Path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: i do it: JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75 | Path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin.
In CMD, when I write the command java -version, appear java version "1.7.0_75". 
i think it's ok, but i still have the problem.

Comment: Have you tried the command "javac" in cmd (to check if jdk is well set) ? Then try going to: Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs and check to see if you have an entry for the path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75. If not, then Click add->Standard VM, then for the JRE Path enter the path from the previous step.  If you had a JRE checked previously then uncheck it.

Comment: (javac -version return: javac 1.7.5_75). And here the properties of the eclipse and my project: 
[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img911/590/GOdCcT.png)
[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/1372/spdmoa.png)

Comment: Have you tried compiling a HelloWorld.jsp ? That's what I used to do to check if my Tomcat server worked.

Comment: i can't put him on tomcat, it's a web project, im only can run as web application. In web application works. 
[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5991/ITgB9p.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but perhaps you could try right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Check here that the JRE is your JDK.